# How to separate messages in a binary networkStream?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, buffer, networkstream

I'm encoding, sending and decoding data using sockets/networkStream. But how can I effectively separate messages from each other ?

For example, when I use a 1024 byte buffer, then receive stuff via networkStream. Then I wanna pass that buffer on to my decoder class, but I'm not sure if part of the next message is already lurking in the buffer. If my message has only 50 bytes, how do I know that there are not 20 messages in that buffer ? Or worse, could there be partial messages in my buffer ?

Let's say my message has 3000 bytes, could there be a message and the start of a second message in a buffer? Or does networkStream automatically receive messages in packages as they were sent ?

Comment: You question looked like your stream. A large chunk of data and no message terminators. I introduced `\n\n` as a terminator in your question.

Answer (score 4):

There are two general choices:

- Send a fixed size header that specifies exactly how long the following message is.
- Send the message followed by a terminator that cannot appear within the message.

All methods of sending variable size binary data through a socket are variations on one of these two themes.

Comment: Send a **fixed size** header. It's obvious, but perhaps worth re-stating

Comment: @caesay, not necessarily. You could use some sort of variable length code (e.g. one of the Elias codes).

Comment: There is a third choice: a self-describing protocol such as XML.

Comment: @EJP: Possibly, but I'd consider it a (stretched) variance of the second one. Every node name has a termination character, and everything generally just has some kind of termination indicator.

Comment: @caesay I would consider it as a third choice. A 'terminator that cannot appear within the message' is not a 'self describing protocol'.

Comment: I would not say that XML is something you should use to detect message boundaries. Way to complex since you have to look for the end of the root node (and it's valid to have an inner node with the same name as the root node). Fixed header is probably the easiest way to go.